# javascript add function script - can someone explain?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

i look for this piece of code in an example that should create functions at object by name.
as i understand it also can create overload of the same function on the object.

```
function addMethod(object, name, fn) {
    var old = object[name];
    object[name] = function(){
        if (fn.length == arguments.length)
            return fn.apply(this, arguments)
        else if (typeof old == 'function')
            return old.apply(this, arguments);
   };
}
```

so If creating a new object like

```
var ninja = {};
```

and than adding functions like:

```
addMethod(ninja,'whatever',function(){ /* do something */ });
addMethod(ninja,'whatever',function(a){ /* do something else */ });
addMethod(ninja,'whatever',function(a,b){ /* yet something else */ });
```

the object should contain 3 overload of the whatever function.

the problem I don't understand addMethod function:

I understand that we store the last function in old.
do we create a closure this way? with the anonymous function?

so for executing this line of code:

```
 else if (typeof old == 'function')
            return old.apply(this, arguments);
```

it will recursively call all the functions defined earlier until match?

can someone explain?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I'll try to explain with example, imagine this:

```
var obj = {
  foo: function() {}
};

var foo2 = function(arg) {};
```

Calling `addMethod(obj, 'foo', foo2)` will replace `obj.foo` with that anonymous function created. Yes, that's a closure, inside it `fn` will always be `foo2`.

Next time you call `obj.foo` the anonymous function will be called. Inside the closure `fn` (that is equal to `foo2`) will have it's `length` equal to the numbers of parameters `foo2` expects to receive and `arguments.length` is equal to number of arguments actually received

```
obj.foo(1);
```

In this case `fn.length` and `arguments.length` are both 1 then `foo2` gets called with the argument I sent.

```
obj.foo();
```

In this case `fn.length` is 1 but `arguments.length` is 0
the closure will check if there's an `old` function and call it passing the arguments (in this case nothing).

If you call `addMethod` again with a new function it will look recursively until it finds a function that receive the same number of arguments sent or until it reaches the last function.

```
var foo3 = function(arg1, arg2) {};
addMethod(obj, 'foo', foo3);

obj.foo(1, 2); // will trigger foo3
obj.foo(1); // will trigger foo2
obj.foo(); // will trigger the original foo
```

Adding a function with the same number of arguments will make the old one never be called again.

```
var foo4 = function(arg) {};
addMethod(obj, 'foo', foo4);

obj.foo(1); // will trigger foo4
```

Comment: I understand that we store the last function in old. do we create a closure this way? with the anonymous function?

so for executing this line of code:
      else if (typeof old == 'function')
                  return old.apply(this, arguments);

it will recursively call all the functions defined earlier until match?

can someone explain?

Comment: Look at the edited answer, I hope I could make myself clear

Answer (score 1):

> but don't understand what we store with the new anonymous function

The point of the code is to call different versions of the function based on the number of arguments passed.

If you don't store the old version of the function somewhere, then there won't be any way to call it.

> why we testing fn.lenth into arguments length (doesn't args.arguments are the 3 always? of (addMethod))

The `length` property of a function is the number of *expected* arguments. i.e. the number of identifiers between the `(` and `)` of the function declaration or function expression that created it.

The `length` property of an `arguments` object is the number of arguments that were actually passed to it.

See this example:

```js
function myFunction(foo, bar) {
  document.body.appendChild(
    document.createElement("br")
  );
  document.body.appendChild(
    document.createTextNode(
      "The function was called with " + arguments.length + " arguments"
    )
  );
}


document.body.appendChild(
  document.createTextNode(
    "The length of the function is " + myFunction.length
  )
);

myFunction();
myFunction("a", "b", "c", "d", "e");
```

Answer (score 0):

> doesn't args.arguments are the 3 always?

No, the `arguments.length` expression is most immediately inside of the *inner* function expression `object[name] = function(){ ... }`, not `addMethod`. Thus, `arguments` refers to the arguments being passed into the function defined on `object[name]` (i.e., the newly-defined function).